# How to let the return Json(datetime) return millisecondes according to the UTC?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a function that retrieves event dates(json format) by ajax. My function should convert the date to a human friendly format. Everything is working but not perfectly. The problem is: 
When the server date is 
"21/06/2013 22h00" this function returns "22/06/2013 05h00"
"26/07/2013 18h30" this function returns "27/07/2013 01h30"

which is 6 hours of advance.

PS: between my country and the country where my server is located, there is a difference of  exactly 6 hours..

Where do I have to put a UTC function? 
what's realy wrong with my function?
Thank you

Here is the code:

```
var jsonifyMyDate = function (jsonDate) {
           var parser = parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6));
           if (parser > 0 && !isNaN(parser)) {
               var newDate = new Date(parser),
               _date = newDate.getDate(),
               _month = newDate.getMonth() + 1,
               _year = newDate.getFullYear(),
               _hour = newDate.getHours(),
               _minute = newDate.getMinutes();
               var dateStr = (_date < 9 ? "0" : "") + _date;
               dateStr += "/" + (_month < 9 ? "0" : "") + _month;
               dateStr += "/" + _year;
               dateStr += " "+(_hour < 9 ? "0" : "") + _hour + "h";
               dateStr += (_minute < 9 ? "0" : "") + _minute;
               /* + "-" + newDate.getSeconds() + "-" + newDate.getMilliseconds() + "";*/
               return dateStr;
           } else return "";
```

UPDATE: I can see the problem with my the server side parsing function within the ActionResult... 
So, as I am using Asp.Net+MVC(C#), How to let the

```
return Json(datetime);
```

return UTC millisecondes instead of the server's one ?

Comment: "Has javascript became server'side ?" No, that's totally absurd. Show us how that function is being called and where its arguments come from.

Comment: I see the problem with my the server side parsing function... as I am using Asp.Net+MVC(C#), 

How to let the "return Json(datetime)" return UTC millisecondes instead of the server's one ?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist you are write I have updated my question... please give it a look. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Json formate is created based on UTC datetime.

After getting the datetime from ajax call, you have to convert this UTC datetime in to local datetime zone.

Ex:

```
var date = new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');
date.toString() // "Wed Jun 29 2011 09:52:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I don't understand well. How Do I have to convert a given date into a local datetime zone? I mean the date can be in the past, in the future, ... 
in my case I have this

var date = new Date(3892832);

how to tell javascript that this is a UTC datetime or not?